# Hot reload of WPF 6.0 core does not work as WindowsBase 4.0.0.0 cannot be changed to 6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, .net-6.0, hot-reload

I have a strange error where I can't get Hot-Reload to work.
I have a WPF application composed of several libraries, both personal and external (nuget) and when I try to modify the code of a WPF window I get the error CS7038, as visual studio tries to change the WindowsBase dll from version 4.0.0.0 to version 6.0.0.0.

In a newly created project this does not happen, so I have an idea that it is the fault of a library that I include.

My question is, how can I figure out who is loading the WindowsBase 4.0.0.0 dll instead of version 6.0.0.0?

Thanks a lot to everyone